# How to determine the type of a MEF plugin class?

Tags: c#, metadata, mef

I'm using [MEF](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mef%20msdn&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx&ei=lduPT46VAsyN4gSu_qm7BA&usg=AFQjCNE_UJdqKA8b6AnLTtwDpa7nJC2hLQ) (C# 4.0) for my plugin system. At times it is necessary to get a list of the derived types of all plugins (mainly for XML deserialization). Can this be done without instantiating the plugin?

This works but requires instantiation:

```
var cat = new DirectoryCatalog(path, "*.dll");
var container = new CompositionContainer(cat);
container.ComposeParts(this);
foreach (var plugin in Plugins)
{
    // Would be better if this could be done via Metadata!
    DoStuff(plugin.Value.GetType());
}
// ...
[ImportMany]
public Lazy<PluginBase, IPluginMetadata>[] Plugins
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

**Q:** Is it possible to accomplish this via some `ExportAttribute`, or some other technique?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEF cannot provide this information by itself. To understand why, consider the following export via a property:

```
[Export(typeof(PluginBase))]
public PluginBase MyPlugin
{
    get
    {
        if (someCondition)
        {
           return new FooPlugin();
        }
        else
        {
           return new BarPlugin();
        }
    }
}
```

However, you can still include the type in the export's metadata (as below or via a custom export attribute that includes the metadata):

```
[Export(typeof(PluginBase))]
[ExportMetadata("Type", typeof(Foo))]
public class Foo : PluginBase
{
}
```

and add a `IPluginMetadata.Type` member.

Comment: Ok, but in this case I need to add this to each derived class, right?

Comment: That's too bad :P But I understand why that's so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a little iteration over ComposableParts, suppose you have a static MEFHelper class that contains a Catalog, you can write this code

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetExportedTypes<T>()
{
    return catalog.Parts
        .Select(part => ComposablePartExportType<T>(part))
        .Where(t => t != null);
}

private static Type ComposablePartExportType<T>(ComposablePartDefinition part)
{

    if (part.ExportDefinitions.Any(
        def => def.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity") &&
            def.Metadata["ExportTypeIdentity"].Equals(typeof(T).FullName)))
    {
        return ReflectionModelServices.GetPartType(part).Value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I explained this in [this blog post](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/getting_the_list_of_type_associated_to_a_given_ex.html) (there is a working sample you can download)